# How to group identical collections together

Tags: python, math, probability

I am randomly sampling a number of matrices A and each one computing the probability mass function (pmf) for Ax.  x is random with elements from +-1 and A is a matrix with elements from +-1.  My code so far looks like:

```
from collections import Counter
import numpy as np
import itertools

def pmf(L):
    C = Counter(L)
    total = float(sum(C.values()))
    for key in C:
        C[key]/=total
    return C

N = 10

h = 2
n = 2**h
X = np.array(list(itertools.product([-1,1],repeat = n))).T

for _ in xrange(N):
    A = (np.random.randint(2, size=(h,n)))*2-1
    B = np.dot(A,X)
    probs = pmf([tuple(x) for x in B.T.tolist()])
    print probs
```

This gives, for example:

```
Counter({(0, 0): 0.375, (2, 2): 0.25, (-2, -2): 0.25, (-4, -4): 0.0625, (4, 4): 0.0625})
Counter({(0, 0): 0.25, (-2, 2): 0.125, (2, 2): 0.125, (2, -2): 0.125, (-2, -2): 0.125, (0, 4): 0.0625, (-4, 0): 0.0625, (4, 0): 0.0625, (0, -4): 0.0625})
Counter({(-2, 0): 0.1875, (0, 2): 0.1875, (2, 0): 0.1875, (0, -2): 0.1875, (-2, -4): 0.0625, (4, 2): 0.0625, (2, 4): 0.0625, (-4, -2): 0.0625})
Counter({(0, 2): 0.1875, (2, 0): 0.1875, (0, -2): 0.1875, (-2, 0): 0.1875, (-4, -2): 0.0625, (-2, -4): 0.0625, (4, 2): 0.0625, (2, 4): 0.0625})
Counter({(0, 0): 0.25, (-2, -2): 0.125, (-2, 2): 0.125, (2, 2): 0.125, (2, -2): 0.125, (-4, 0): 0.0625, (0, 4): 0.0625, (0, -4): 0.0625, (4, 0): 0.0625})
Counter({(0, 0): 0.25, (2, -2): 0.125, (2, 2): 0.125, (-2, -2): 0.125, (-2, 2): 0.125, (-4, 0): 0.0625, (0, 4): 0.0625, (0, -4): 0.0625, (4, 0): 0.0625})
Counter({(-2, 0): 0.1875, (2, 0): 0.1875, (0, -2): 0.1875, (0, 2): 0.1875, (-4, 2): 0.0625, (4, -2): 0.0625, (-2, 4): 0.0625, (2, -4): 0.0625})
Counter({(-2, 0): 0.1875, (2, 0): 0.1875, (0, -2): 0.1875, (0, 2): 0.1875, (-4, 2): 0.0625, (4, -2): 0.0625, (-2, 4): 0.0625, (2, -4): 0.0625})
Counter({(2, 0): 0.1875, (0, -2): 0.1875, (0, 2): 0.1875, (-2, 0): 0.1875, (-4, -2): 0.0625, (-2, -4): 0.0625, (2, 4): 0.0625, (4, 2): 0.0625})
Counter({(0, 0): 0.25, (-2, -2): 0.125, (-2, 2): 0.125, (2, 2): 0.125, (2, -2): 0.125, (-4, 0): 0.0625, (0, 4): 0.0625, (0, -4): 0.0625, (4, 0): 0.0625})
```

I can collect together all the collections which are identical by hand and count how many I have of each. For example using the above output:

```
2     Counter({(-2, 0): 0.1875, (2, 0): 0.1875, (0, -2): 0.1875, (0, 2): 0.1875, (-4, 2): 0.0625, (4, -2): 0.0625, (-2, 4): 0.0625, (2, -4): 0.0625})
2     Counter({(0, 0): 0.25, (-2, -2): 0.125, (-2, 2): 0.125, (2, 2): 0.125, (2, -2): 0.125, (-4, 0): 0.0625, (0, 4): 0.0625, (0, -4): 0.0625, (4, 0): 0.0625})
1     Counter({(-2, 0): 0.1875, (0, 2): 0.1875, (2, 0): 0.1875, (0, -2): 0.1875, (-2, -4): 0.0625, (4, 2): 0.0625, (2, 4): 0.0625, (-4, -2): 0.0625})
1     Counter({(2, 0): 0.1875, (0, -2): 0.1875, (0, 2): 0.1875, (-2, 0): 0.1875, (-4, -2): 0.0625, (-2, -4): 0.0625, (2, 4): 0.0625, (4, 2): 0.0625})
1     Counter({(0, 2): 0.1875, (2, 0): 0.1875, (0, -2): 0.1875, (-2, 0): 0.1875, (-4, -2): 0.0625, (-2, -4): 0.0625, (4, 2): 0.0625, (2, 4): 0.0625})
1     Counter({(0, 0): 0.375, (2, 2): 0.25, (-2, -2): 0.25, (-4, -4): 0.0625, (4, 4): 0.0625})
1     Counter({(0, 0): 0.25, (2, -2): 0.125, (2, 2): 0.125, (-2, -2): 0.125, (-2, 2): 0.125, (-4, 0): 0.0625, (0, 4): 0.0625, (0, -4): 0.0625, (4, 0): 0.0625})
1     Counter({(0, 0): 0.25, (-2, 2): 0.125, (2, 2): 0.125, (2, -2): 0.125, (-2, -2): 0.125, (0, 4): 0.0625, (-4, 0): 0.0625, (4, 0): 0.0625, (0, -4): 0.0625})
```

However, what I would like is for each of these groups of identical collections to look at the matrices that caused them. So this would be two matrices for the first two groups above and 1 each for all the rest.

What would be a good way to do this?

Comment: I didn't vote to close it, but I can see that the someone voted it as being "unclear what you're asking" -- so perhaps you can clarify a bit.

Comment: @JohnColeman I updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as you want to group each one by value, you can make a new dict with key the pmf-value and value a list/set of the matrix you have, and to help in this you can use a defaultdict with list/set. like this

```
from collections import Counter, defaultdict

test = Counter({(0, 0): 0.25, (-2, -2): 0.125, (-2, 2): 0.125, (2, 2): 0.125, (2, -2): 0.125, (-4, 0): 0.0625, (0, 4): 0.0625, (0, -4): 0.0625, (4, 0): 0.0625})

result = defaultdict(list)
for k,v in test.iteritems():
    result[v].append(k)
print result

#or more readable 
for k,v in result.iteritems():
    print k,v
```

output

```
0.25 [(0, 0)]
0.125 [(2, 2), (2, -2), (-2, -2), (-2, 2)]
0.0625 [(-4, 0), (0, 4), (0, -4), (4, 0)]
```

**EDIT**

Now, if you want to get the matrix `A` that produce a particular *pmf-value*, getting that from the *pmf-value* alone is imposible, so is needed to work around that by keeping track of each matrix that produce a particular *pmf-value* with the same defaultdict approach as before with the *pmf* as key and value a list of the matrix with that *pmf*, like this:

```
from collections import Counter, defaultdict
import numpy as np
import itertools

def pmf(L):
    C = Counter(L)
    total = float(sum(C.values()))
    for key in C:
        C[key]/=total
    return C

N = 10

h = 2
n = 2**h
X = np.array(list(itertools.product([-1,1],repeat = n))).T

result = defaultdict(list)

for _ in xrange(N):
    A = (np.random.randint(2, size=(h,n)))*2-1
    B = np.dot(A,X)
    probs = pmf([tuple(x) for x in B.T.tolist()])
    print probs
    result[ frozenset(probs.items()) ].append( A ) #append the one you need
```

now this part `frozenset(probs.items())` is because a *Counter* is a unhashable object because is mutable and as such can't be used a dict key, so I need make it immutable by converting it to a *frozenset* of its items.

With this, now we have all the matrix that have a particular *pmf*

output

```
>>> for k,v in result.items():
        print k
        for A in v:
            print A
            print ""
        print "--------------------"


frozenset({((-4, 2), 0.0625), ((2, 0), 0.1875), ((4, -2), 0.0625), ((0, 2), 0.1875), ((-2, 4), 0.0625), ((0, -2), 0.1875), ((-2, 0), 0.1875), ((2, -4), 0.0625)})
[[ 1  1 -1  1]
 [-1 -1  1  1]]

[[ 1  1 -1 -1]
 [-1  1  1  1]]

--------------------
frozenset({((2, 0), 0.1875), ((-2, -4), 0.0625), ((2, 4), 0.0625), ((0, 2), 0.1875), ((4, 2), 0.0625), ((0, -2), 0.1875), ((-2, 0), 0.1875), ((-4, -2), 0.0625)})
[[-1  1  1 -1]
 [ 1  1  1 -1]]

[[ 1  1  1 -1]
 [ 1 -1  1 -1]]

[[-1  1 -1  1]
 [-1  1  1  1]]

--------------------
frozenset({((0, 0), 0.25), ((-2, 2), 0.125), ((2, -2), 0.125), ((0, -4), 0.0625), ((0, 4), 0.0625), ((-4, 0), 0.0625), ((2, 2), 0.125), ((-2, -2), 0.125), ((4, 0), 0.0625)})
[[-1 -1 -1  1]
 [ 1  1 -1  1]]

[[-1  1  1 -1]
 [-1 -1 -1 -1]]

[[-1 -1 -1 -1]
 [ 1 -1  1 -1]]

[[ 1  1 -1  1]
 [ 1 -1  1  1]]

[[ 1  1  1  1]
 [-1 -1  1  1]]

--------------------
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you but this isn't quite what I wanted. I have updated the question.

Comment: now I don't understand what you want, you want to get the matrix that generate those Counter from the Counters? if so witch one? A or B or both?

Comment: I make a edit, now, if I understand correctly, that is what you want, right?